# Игнорируется Xceed PropertyGrid's Editor

Tags: c#, propertygrid

Я написал редактор к для `Xceed PropertyGrid`, который должен возвращать путь при помощи `FolderBrowseDialog`. Этот редактор приложением просто игнорируется...

```
private string _drivePath;

[Browsable(true)]
[Editor(typeof(FolderPathEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
public string DrivePath
{
  get { return _drivePath; }
  set
      {
        _drivePath = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
      } 
}
```

Код редактора:

```
public class FolderPathEditor : UITypeEditor
{

    public FolderPathEditor()
    {
    }

    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        if (context == null || context.Instance == null || provider == null)
        {
            return base.EditValue(context, provider, value);
        }

        using (FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath = value.ToString();
            }

            folderBrowserDialog.Description = context.PropertyDescriptor.DisplayName;

            if (folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                value = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
            }
        }

        return value;
    }

}
```